# let's say I am writing my code and then my PC died, how necessary is it to do a complete scan if i don't want my later source code to be contaminated?

Tags: bsod

let's say I am writing a Ruby on Rails program and while editing a file, the machine blue screened.  in this case, how necessary is it to re-scan the whole hard drive if I don't want my future files to be damaged?

Let's say if the OS is deleting a tmp file at the moment when my computer crashed, and still have some pointers to some sector on the hard drive.  and if my newly created files happen to be in those sector, and next time the OS clean up files again, it may think that the "left-over" sector wasn't cleaned last time and clean it again, and damaging our source code.  (esp with Ruby on Rails, where the source code could be generated by rails and not by us, and we may not know why our rails server doesn't work, if a file is affected).  we can rely on SVN, but what if the file is affected before we check it in?

i think the official answer will be: "always scan the disk after a crash or power outage, for the data and even the space and indicate attempt to fix any bad sector", but the thing is, nowadays with the hard drive so big, it could take 2 hours to scan everything.  And especially at work, we cannot wait for 2 hours if it is the middle of the day.

Does someone know if the modern OS, like XP, Vista, Mac OS, and Linux (when sometimes the power cord was loose and it didn't shut down properly and just shut down on 0% battery), with these modern OS, are our source code safe?  Do they know how to structure to write to sector so that at most it will waste sector instead of overlapping sectors?

Comment: If you're that worried, then yes scan the drive. Sorry if it takes 2 hours in the middle of the day. I guess you should have a Disaster Recovery Plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a modern journaling file system (ext3/4, NTFS), the only problem would be that a file could be in a "half-written" state. Obviously scanning is not going to help this (that's what backups are for). The file system itself could not be corrupted. If you are using something like FAT, then yes, you should worry about this.

Answer (score 2):

There's really only 1 issue here.

Is any file currently being written in some kind of "half written" state.

The primary cause of this would be if the application/editor is writing the file and the machine dies halfway through. In this case, the file be written is, well, half done. If it was over writing the original file, the original file is "gone", and the new one is "half done". If you don't have a back up file, then, well, you have a problem.

As far as a file having dangling pointers, or references to sectors not written, or somesuch thing. That problem depends on your file system.

The major, modern files ystems are journaled and "won't allow" this to happen. You may have a "half written", but that's because the application only got to write half of it, rather than the file system losing track of a sector pointer.

If you're playing file system games for performance, or whatever (such as using a UFS without logging), then you would want to run a fschk to clean up the file systems meta data.

But if you're using a modern operating system and file system (i.e. anything from the past 5 years), you won't have this problem.

Finally, if you do have version control running, then just do an "svn status", it will show you any "corrupted" files as they will have changed and it will detect that as well.

Answer (score 0):

i see some information on

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system

Journalized file systems

File systems may provide journaling, which provides safe recovery in the event of a system crash. A journaled file system writes some information twice: first to the journal, which is a log of file system operations, then to its proper place in the ordinary file system. Journaling is handled by the file system driver, and keeps track of each operation taking place that changes the contents of the disk. In the event of a crash, the system can recover to a consistent state by replaying a portion of the journal. Many UNIX file systems provide journaling including ReiserFS, JFS, and Ext3.

In contrast, non-journaled file systems typically need to be examined in their entirety by a utility such as fsck or chkdsk for any inconsistencies after an unclean shutdown. Soft updates is an alternative to journaling that avoids the redundant writes by carefully ordering the update operations. Log-structured file systems and ZFS also differ from traditional journaled file systems in that they avoid inconsistencies by always writing new copies of the data, eschewing in-place updates.